# Can child content types have separate metadata site column anchor points?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, managed-metadata, site-column

I am trying to solve an issue in SharePoint Online which I don't remember seeing in SharePoint 2010 or 2013.

Say a parent content type has metadata column: European Cities which points to term group with multiple term sets: English Cities, French Cities, German Cities)

Now I want each of my child content types to have unique anchor point for the same Site column.  How can this be done  in the same SharePoint list.

An example could be an  order locations list. When a user creates new content

- child content type 1: English Cities has city meta column that starts with England
- child content type 2: German Cities has city meta column that starts with Germany

I have tried both site collection and site level: content types. I have also tried having  a single term set but so far I seem only to set the **same** default anchor point,  for every child content type.

Daniel

Comment: If you wanted different anchor points for the children, you wouldn't include it in the parent. It would be added in each child so it could be configured differently in each of them iirc.

Comment: is that the same site column and is that both at the web level and the site collection level ..

Comment: @EricAlexander I think whey I never saw this issue in sp2010 because my content types were assigned to different lists on different team sites. I  don't fancy adding the same site column to each content type but it's look like I'll have to.